# Limit indicator function

Tags: real-analysis

I am currently struggling with a very simple exercise, I guess.

I don't see why $$\lim_{n \to \infty} n\mathbb{1}_{(0,\frac{1}{n})}=0, $$ where $\mathbb{1}_{(0,\frac{1}{n})}$ is the indicator function.

Thanks

Comment: On what variable does that indicator function is being applied? Perhaps I miss something trivial here, but the expression $\;\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} n\cdot f\;$ , with $\;f\;$ some function, doesn't make much sense unless we specify some variable for $\;f\;$ ...

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you meant $\;n\cdot 1_{\left(0,\frac1n\right)}(x)\;$ , for **any (some) fixed** $\;x\in\Bbb R\;$, we get that there exists some $\;N\in\Bbb N\;$ s.t. for $\;n>N\implies 1_{\left(1,\frac1n\right)}(x)=0\;$ , and thus $\;n\cdot 1_{\left(1,\frac1n\right)}(x)=0\;$ for all $\;n>N\;$ , which of course means the limit is zero...